# did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 431 column 15

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

[image]

I was trying to create a proxy_protocol policy for elb in Cloud formation template in YAML format. I was getting an error "did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 431 column 15". I was trying to run the AWS cli commands while the CFN templates are created and passing required parameters. How to resolve the issue and run the AWS cli commands through CFN templates?

```
Proxy_policy:
          commands:
            01_Enable_proxy:
              command: "$(aws --region", !Ref "AWS::Region", " elb create-load-balancer-policy ",
                                "         --load-balancer-name ", !Ref "AppELB",
                                "         --policy-name ", !Join [ "", [!FindInMap [EnvironmentToPrettyEnvironmentMap, !Ref "Environment", label], ProxyProtocol]] ,
                                "         --policy-type-name ProxyProtocolPolicyType",
                                "         --policy-attributes AttributeName=ProxyProtocol,AttributeValue=True)"                
        set_listener:
          commands:
            01_set_listener:
              command: "$(aws --region", !Ref "AWS::Region", "elb set-load-balancer-policies-for-backend-server",
                                "   --load-balancer-name ",!Ref "AppELB", 
                                "   --policy-names ",!Join [ "", [!FindInMap [EnvironmentToPrettyEnvironmentMap, !Ref "Environment", label], ProxyProtocol]],
                                "   --instance-port 80")
```

Comment: Your YAML doesn't seem to be a valid YAML file because of the indentation for the first `commands` not being equal to that for `set_listener`.

Comment: That error is coming from their Yaml parser. You don't have valid Yaml.

Comment: i tired it but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

```
Proxy_policy:
          commands:
            01_Proxy_policy:
              command: !Join ["", [ 
                               "  $(aws --region ", !Ref "AWS::Region" , " elb create-load-balancer-policy ",
                               "              --load-balancer-name ", !Ref "AppELB", 
                               "              --policy-name ", !Join [ "", [!FindInMap [EnvironmentToPrettyEnvironmentMap, !Ref "Environment", label], ProxyProtocol]] ,
                               "              --policy-type-name ProxyProtocolPolicyType ",
                               "              --policy-attributes AttributeName=ProxyProtocol,AttributeValue=True); " ]]                  
        set_listener:
          commands:
            01_set_listener:
              command: !Join ["", [
                               "  $(aws --region ", !Ref "AWS::Region", " elb set-load-balancer-policies-for-backend-server ",
                               "              --load-balancer-name ", !Ref "AppELB", 
                               "              --policy-names ", !Join [ "", [!FindInMap [EnvironmentToPrettyEnvironmentMap, !Ref "Environment", label], ProxyProtocol]] ,
                               "              --instance-port 80); " ]][enter image description here][1]
```